# How to configure quotes strategy in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'am try to move from mysql to postgresql and stuck on ansi quotes in upper case fields names.

I read the chapter about Doctrine quotes strategies in the manual. Unfortunately I don't understand where I have to put the configuration code.

In order to get an ansi quote strategy I should use this code:

```
$configuration->setQuoteStrategy(new AnsiQuoteStrategy());
```

I'm on Symfony 2 — I guess this matters when it comes to configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doctrine-bundle 1.5+.

Configure it in **config.yml**:

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        quote_strategy: doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.ansi
```

For multiple entity managers:

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        entity_managers:
            default:
                quote_strategy: doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.ansi
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen, you're going to have to get down and dirty with the service container. The Doctrine bundle does not currently allow you to set the quote strategy, so the cleanest way to achieve this would be to augment the current services defined in the Doctrine Bundle.

1. [Create an overriding compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration).
2. [Enable the compiler pass in your bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.htm).

I haven't the time to fully test this code, but it will look very much like this when it's done...

**# MyBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/DoctrineQuoteStrategyCompilerPass.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class DoctrineQuoteStrategyCompilerPass extends CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Create a new service out of the ANSI quote strategy.
        $ansiQuoteStrategy = new Definition(
            'Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\AnsiQuoteStrategy'
        );
        $container->setDefinition('doctrine.ansi_quote_strategy', $ansiQuoteStrategy);

        // Add this to orm configuration calls.
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('doctrine.orm.default_configuration');
        $definition->addMethodCall('setQuoteStrategy', array(new Reference('doctrine.ansi_quote_strategy')));
    }
}
```

**MyBundle/MyBundleBundle.php** (*Bundle.php file in bundle directory)

```
<?php

use MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineQuoteStrategyCompilerPass;

class MyBundleBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        ...

        $container->addCompilerPass(new DoctrineQuoteStrategyCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

**Warning**

This code assumes that you have your own application bundle defined somewhere (which is best practice). It also assumes that you only have one entity manager defined, which is the most likely. If this isn't the case, you must use the proper entity manager names (change "default" to "myname").